# Some error on constructor and recursion i don't seem to understand

Tags: javascript

I'm working on constructor, at first I was using ES5 and my error was "Message is not a function" then I saw something about arrow function not been used with constructor so I removed it and got another error saying "Maximum call stack size exceeded" something about recursion. I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong. have seen a lot of answers on constructor but none of them seems helpful.

```
function Message(name, motive, hubby){
 this.name = name
 this.motive  = motive
 this.hubby = hubby
 this.output=function(){
return `Hi, i'm ${this.name} i love ${this.hubby} and i would love to be your ${this.motive}.`
}
 var Mymessage = new Message('josephine','friend', 'coding');
 console.log(Mymessage.output()); 
}
 Message();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Message(name, motive, hubby){
 this.name = name
 this.motive  = motive
 this.hubby = hubby
 this.output=function(){
  return `Hi, i'm ${this.name} i love ${this.hubby} and i would love to be your ${this.motive}.`
  }
}
 var Mymessage = new Message('josephine','friend', 'coding');
 console.log(Mymessage.output()); 
 Message();
```

You must write var Mymessage outside the Message function , as you have called it inside the same function, that line of code is calling itself again and again which is causing an erro .

Comment: Hey , If this solution was helpful , accept the answer and kindly up vote , so that other users can find the correct solution more easily , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should create an instance and call a function of that instance

```
function Message(name, motive, hubby){
     this.name = name
     this.motive  = motive
     this.hubby = hubby
     this.output=function(){
    return `Hi, i'm ${this.name} i love ${this.hubby} and i would love to be your ${this.motive}.`
    }
}
var Mymessage = new Message('josephine','friend', 'coding');
console.log(Mymessage.output());
```